# Consequences of moving linux users home to non default directory

Tags: linux, security, home-directory

I'am wondering what the consequences in linux can be when we assign non default home directory to the users. 
So, use e.g. /encrypted-home/user instead of /home (that is, btw, also the reason why i am asking)
I've already noticed that X-server doesn't function properly and additional configuration is required (i.e. cannot connect to X server).
 What else could be a potential source of issues?
Is changing default home dir a good practice?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the home directory is properly set in `/etc/passwd` (or LDAP etc.) for a given user, there should be no consequence at all for any well-maintained system. Of course, if you run something that expects the home directory to be `/home/username` instead of `$HOME` (or other ways to get the actual home dir), you might run into trouble but such a thing is not worth using anyway. Even with X11, I never experienced any issues with non-standard home directories. What do you mean with "additional config is required"?

Of course you have to make sure that e.g. `/encrypted-home` is backed up as well.

Comment: ok thanks. The case where apps use hard-coded links, will be taken care of by creating a link between /home/user and /ecrypted-home/user

Comment: I just did some tests. I noticed that one of the Drawbacks is SELinux, which can become a tricky configuration.